# Car hesitates when starting on a cold start

Tags: starting

Sometimes when I start my car it hesitates, like an extention of its normal starts.. it doesn't make a ticking noise so it's not the battery I've had that and the alternator checked already.  I took it in cuz it threw a code that the intake valve was sticking get which was fixed but it is still hesitating at times.. I wanna say it's when it's cold.. any thoughts?!?

Comment: This is pretty broad.  We wil need more information (make, model, year, engine size) as well as any current or prior "codes" you have experienced.

Comment: Can I up vote Steve's comment twice? Yes, need a ton more information to even come close to being able to answer.

Comment: A good place to start with clarifying this question is with explaining more about the hesitation. I think you describing something that happens when you try to start the car, is that right? And that it happens more when the car is cold. Is the hesitation between when you turn the key and the engine starts to crank? Or does it start cranking right away, but it is slow to start running? Or is it something else? And yes, the details that @SteveRacer asked for are critical as well.

Comment: Some key information is missing here, namely what make / model of car is it and what fuel type.  The answer for a diesel will be very different to that for a petrol.

Comment: OP, anymore details, or resolution of this issue?